# How to use django-avatar with my own User model and not with django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: python, django, avatar

I would like to use **django-avatar** with my own model. Is it possible to do that?

**login/models.py**

```
class LoginInfo(models.Model):
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    login = models.OneToOneField(Login, primary_key=True) # contain user_name, pw, mail
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you created a custom User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [django-avatar models.py](https://github.com/jezdez/django-avatar/blob/master/avatar/models.py)

```
66. class Avatar(models.Model):
67.     user = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User'))
68.     ....
```

the code seem to be ready to accept custom User model, however, you can always git clone and change it as you wish...

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to see an answer! I'll check it tomorrow morning.

Comment: And how do I connect my custom model with the avatar class?

Comment: something like `'AUTH_USER_MODEL='your.model.User'` in django settings.py

Answer (score 1):

Another option for a simple avatar is django-easy-avatar.  It has just has a foreign key relationship to the user table and requires no templates unless you want to override default functionality.